# I'm trying to test making a background for a project I have in Kivy, but when I run the program it debug without errors but not run the program

Tags: python, android, visual-studio-code, kivy

the code is like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle



class CustomWidget(Widget):
    pass

class CustomWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # set background image
        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source=r'C:\tnwebat\HDF 5.0 Stream Edition\HDFgame3\base\background\999cargo\defenseempty.png',
                                pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_bg, size=self.update_bg)

    def update_bg(self, *args):
        self.bg.pos = self.pos
        self.bg.size = self.size

class CustomApp(App):
    def build(self):
        widget = CustomWidget()
        return widget
```

and I'm running it on VS Code

I was expecting the program to run and show the image from my PC. and didn't open a window with the app and it didn't show me any error, even though I tried to run some other codes like a button with the "hello world" on it and it worked.

is there a problem in the code? is it not actually possible? thank you

Comment: Try copying the `png` file into the same folder where your python code is and simplify the `source` string to just the file name (without the path). Just as a test to see if there is a problem with the path.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Kivy's dependencies have been installed.

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
```